# Premiere writes the text in the wrong side

Tags: premiere

I'm trying to write a title on a video but Premiere writes in in the wrong side : from right to left. Let me show you, when I try to write HR, I have  RH

[image: HR is written RH]

And when I add "&AI" I got "&AI".

[image: "IA&RH& rather than "HR&AI"]

Can you help me writting it in the left to right side, that is to say to have "HR&AI" ?

Answer (score 1):

Check under your Preferences in the 'Graphics' section that the 'Default Paragraph Dirction' is not right-to-left.

After adjusting the setting, you may need to create a new text layer to see the changes take place.

[image]